# How to view the html and text generated by Active

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I don't want to actually send the email, I just want to be able to view the email that action mailer generates for both the HTML and TEXT email types.

So something like:

```
html = UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).html
text = UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).text
```

Is this possible?

**Update**

I am trying this backport render out: https://github.com/brainopia/backport_new_renderer/blob/master/backport_new_renderer.rb

I have this so far:

```
class EmailController < ActionController::Base
    layout "email"

    def welcome
    end
end
```

My /app/views/email/welcome.html.erb is just:

```
Hello <%= @name %>
```

Then I created a lib/rasks/render.rake file that looks like:

```
desc "testing controller rendering backport"
task :render do
    puts "hello render"
    @name = "adf"
    EmailController.render(:welcome)
end
```

error is:

```
hello render
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant EmailController
/Users/path/to/apps/myapp/lib/tasks/render.rake:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => render
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Could you share the motivation behind this? Maybe we know a different way to solve the underlaying need.

Comment: @Leito I am using mailgun and want full-control on how I send the email, but want to use action mailer just for the templating functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Rails 5, you can render a template using:

```
ActionController.render('mailer/mymailer.html.erb', assigns: { a: b })
```

But as the poster above mentioned, you likely just want to preview the email. The [letter_opener](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener) gem is good. I recently discovered and love [Mailcatcher](https://mailcatcher.me).

Comment: I'm on rails 4 darn!  It isn't for preview but for sending to mailgun.

Comment: It's [possible in Rails 4](https://coderwall.com/p/p_yelg/render-view-outside-of-a-controller-in-rails-4). And there is a [back-port of Rails 5 functionality](https://github.com/brainopia/backport_new_renderer) as well.

Comment: That isn't a published gem, how can I include it?

Comment: It's [published for me](https://rubygems.org/gems/backport_new_renderer/versions/1.0.0). But you can always `gem 'backport_new_renderer', git: 'https://github.com/brainopia/backport_new_renderer.git'`

Comment: I updated my question, not sure how to pass in the locals.  What is the diff between locals and assigns?

Comment: This is a Rake task issue now, I think you need to change to `task :render => :environment do`

Comment: Can I set the format if I want text or html template to render? e.g.  welcome.text.erb or welcome.html.erb

Comment: `.render('template', assigns: {a: b}, formats: [:html])`

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you want this so you can validate the appearance of the email.

There is a gem written by the creator of RailsCasts Ryan Bates called `letter_opener`.

It lets you set the delivery method in development as `:letter_opener` (instead of `:smtp` or anything else) and when an email is sent by your app a browser window opens showing you the content and layout of your email.

https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener